# Is there a way to combine the power of a DB with the transparency and simplicity of a textual file base?

Tags: python, database, filesystems, text-files

I've just discovered [Sir](https://github.com/c9fe/sirdb) - a database based on text files, but it's far from ready and it's written in JS (i.e. not for me).

My first intuition was to ask if there's something like this available for Python or C++, but since that's not the kind of question one should ask on Stackoverflow let me put it more general:

I like the way e.g. `git` is made - it stores data as easy to handle separate files and it's astonishingly fast at the same time. Moreover git does not require a server which holds data in memory to be fast (the filesystem cache is doing a good enough job) and - maybe the best part - the way git keeps data in "memory" (the filesystem) is intrinsically language agnostic.

Of course `git` is not a database and databases have different challenges to master but I still dare to ask: are there generic approaches to make databases as transparent and manually modifiable as `git` is?

Are there keywords, examples, generally accepted concepts or working projects (like [Sir](https://github.com/c9fe/sirdb) but preferably Python or C++ based) I should learn to know if I want to enhance my fuzzy filesystem polluting project with a database-like fast technology, providing a nice query language without having to sacrifice the simplicity to just manually edit/copy/overwrite files on the filesystem?

Comment: Well, good luck managing text files and doing updates and insertions. It used to be done with fixed size records in the past. Now, the closest I see t what you wish for would be a text storage engine used in conjunction with mysql.

Comment: I think it depends on whether you want to have a database for millions of queries by dozens or hundreds of threads or if you want a single process application save configuration, states, cache etc. consistently with performance and searchablility in mind

Comment: When do people manually edit git objects on file system without using `git` command?

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) is exactly what you are looking for. It is built in into Python as well: [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

It's just not human readable, but neither is git. It is purely serverless based on files however, just like git.

Comment: +1 for SQLite because it has some properties I've asked for. but regarding manual modifications and transparency being non human readable/writable is just not, what I'm _really_ looking for

Comment: @frans You can do manual modifications using the `sqlite` command line tool (as well as various GUI editors). Human readable/writable is just not really realistic in combination with a database that tries to be efficient as well as *correct* (that is, when you commit a SQL transaction it always succeeds or rolls back to the previous state in case of failure, and more, see [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)).

Comment: @frans Even a text file is not human readable without a tool to open it and display the content, albeit simpler than a database. Behind the text editor sits the O.S. and a sophisticated file system. So, no matter what, you are always dealing with abstractions. As such, concentrate on the tool that gets the job done.